# Is there a way to type hint a class property created without the property decorator?

Tags: python, properties, type-hinting

Consider writing an interface class in Python. The interface hides getter and setter methods behind properties. There are several properties that have a very similar structure and only differ by their name. To reduce code duplication, the interface uses a factory method for its properties:

```
from __future__ import annotations


class Interface:

    def property_factory(name: str) -> property:
        """Create a property depending on the name."""

        @property
        def _complex_property(self: Interface) -> str:
            # Do something complex with the provided name
            return name

        @_complex_property.setter
        def _complex_property(self: Interface, _: str):
            pass

        return _complex_property

    foo = property_factory("foo")  # Works just like an actual property
    bar = property_factory("bar")


def main():
    interface = Interface()
    interface.foo  # Is of type '(variable) foo: Any' instead of '(property) foo: str'


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

One issue with this implementation is that `Interface.foo` and `Interface.bar` will be marked as `(variable) foo/bar: Any`, even though they should be `(property) foo/bar: str`. Is there a way to type hint foo and bar properly?

Using an inline type hint like

```
foo: str = property_factory("foo")
```

feels misleading because foo is not really a string.

I'm not dead set on this property pattern. If there is a better way to create the properties I'd also be happy to change that. However, keep in mind that the interface requires properties as the real code does more complex stuff in the getter/setter methods. Also, I want to keep the properties instead of having a general method like get_property(self, name: str).

I can also share the actual code I'm working on, the above example is just a minimal example of what I have in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wild speculation: `property_factory` is type hinted to return `property`; the type of the decorated method/function is lost, which normally wouldn't happen since a type checker would also check that if it were used inside the body of a class.

`property` [is not generic](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/8440) (yet). However, the linked issue's OP themself provided a generic child class of `property` as a possible solution. That was nearly 4 years ago when the type system is not anywhere as good as it currently is, so let's rewrite the class:

```py
from typing import Any, Generic, TypeVar, overload, cast

T = TypeVar('T')  # The return type
I = TypeVar('I')  # The outer instance's type

class Property(property, Generic[I, T]):
    
    def __init__(
        self,
        fget: Callable[[I], T] | None = None,
        fset: Callable[[I, T], None] | None = None,
        fdel: Callable[[I], None] | None = None,
        doc: str | None = None
    ) -> None:
        super().__init__(fget, fset, fdel, doc)
    
    @overload
    def __get__(self, instance: None, owner: type[I] | None = None) -> Callable[[I], T]:
        ...
    
    @overload
    def __get__(self, instance: I, owner: type[I] | None = None) -> T:
        ...
    
    def __get__(self, instance: I | None, owner: type[I] | None = None) -> Callable[[I], T] | T:
        return cast(Callable[[I], T] | T, super().__get__(instance, owner))
    
    def __set__(self, instance: I, value: T) -> None:
        super().__set__(instance, value)
    
    def __delete__(self, instance: I) -> None:
        super().__delete__(instance)
```

The rest of the methods can also be re-type-hinted this way, but that's an exercise for the reader. Now that we have a generic `property` class, the original design can be rewritten as:

<sub>(The original works too, just use `-> Property[Interface, str]`/`return Property(_getter, _setter)`.)</sub>

```py
from collections.abc import Callable

Getter = Callable[['Interface'], str]
Setter = Callable[['Interface', str], None]

def complex_property(name: str) -> tuple[Getter, Setter]:
    def _getter(self: Interface) -> str:
        ...
    
    def _setter(self: Interface, value: str) -> None:
        ...
    
    return _getter, _setter
```

...which can then be used as:

```py
class Interface:
    
    foo = Property(*complex_property("foo"))
```

Assuming `bar` is a normal `@property` of the same class, here are some tests ([mypy playground](https://mypy-play.net/?flags=strict&mypy=latest&python=3.12&gist=bc928d549536b67e73d8c686aecd1ac1), [pyright playground](https://pyright-play.net/?strict=true&reportPropertyTypeMismatch=true&code=GYJw9gtgBA%2BjwFcAuCQFM5QJYQA5hCSgEMA7UsJYpLMUgZwChHRIokBPXLUgc2zwEiAcTSk0ILAGMANFAAqXNADViIOWABuEgDZhiAEzlTi9JM1bQpYHTrRSadegDpiAIykD8hKAGFitu52zIyiSEgSUAC8fgE6QWgA2okA5ACSpBEgwMRSaCkAunJmIAWMAMpo4ZEx-oFudsnpmRI5eSnFSKVyAHJ0aGXM8tEKSqogABQp8ikAlIxpI4q4KmpTaXMhUvH09FAACuArhBwTuEcSnHKi4pJSiWly8gWzAFyMUJ9QH18GaMCwGA8LBIOATH5fL70NA6YAyCGQqDAXhVV6xeqNB5FBQFKAAHygfXEIyJaHhiK%2BwGhSDRdXiDSSDye2NJuIJpJJ-XJFKRfx0tLiCWSaRZ-TZhP6nPE3IpBjAUjRJXxEuJMVJCNmUAAtAA%2BFVod48qD0BDHCazZxwYGgmATZFVORUh28mFyOVSeaQhEAAS0un0BgRfwBcBRNom0Nhch4ZjIeTRpI0AHdbmjOCsscqOWr%2Bprdej6ZiRczDTznOWET6-SA9IYg-9AWGwZG4dgGFRSPGoI8oGAUxI00pM%2BzJTnxHm9fJSxTy85K5Dg42qs2Ya2Yx2u4sR9Le-2QIOMyKs6P9ROC0KsczlVOEZD0CgQKQoCYzBM6Rfizjr8VTRJzZaYCbW11zjMld1uWZPS%2BesQxgakVyjNtY07A1uzkTQAgQVD5DPUlp0RE0zQtOB4OA9tQPQzC0Cgz4YMBPkqgwW0W2jciULRNJcP6fDIUIv9iJgBiIjBECUPmZhF2sPA7AADxgc4wGOTgJlIYgIFQkozxQXBGjCLI5EqapSnwxdAKqLII1XDiWmyXJqO1PUSh4r5Z3nX4Gzg8y-xbaysjaMCMJ0LDFS6LjxGcz5XK9O8qlQJ8zKMuRPKMrYdj2DI-Ls-CEWAMAwBGQ5FMuU4ACopJ0tA5IUpTTgAIlysBasgtzPm9arirotw1hbM8nNvFyKyNH0upAZxqSyTrutXSigo00KHP1CKoFc5hRLyEYMtaOzzWYdBtACGB0zQCZNtsvJnAazUoAAYigCAuA4SEoj1E6bP83qun6o1vsRW7cA4SReAACyIZ6oFezK8g%2BkBdrQfadEOpQIa286Rqu277v%2Bp6XtO96FpKL6fqJv6AawYHQb1dqTlh%2BHEZWCY1rQC68qum67oeqAAGooH%2BwGQeiRzPr2tADqOhm2NRtRWYxjnud5sn%2BbBgnGEZ5n8piAAWAAmYn2axr4wYkcB927TtIFwagsAZdglD2HgSF2MnSHUzJCaJ76Sb5imoCNgg0VqgAZEEJACRJtYKWrsDts28Et62kxBIGoFqkpI6mBqUijqAEFIP4ax4NADHE1WRpGbXdcxx6Db1X2TYycq47sG2Vmjh36Cdl3zHd7uvk9hXvdr-2g6yUPw8jrBo4bmh48T5PU-BlJtczifs9z3QC6L1aJaZhqRhSPR0AgTPfr1x65dJ8mBaRAuVe35xS5iFIsFwE0j4pGWsfPr2r%2BAG%2BgA)):

```py
reveal_type(Interface.foo)  # mypy    => (Interface) -> str
                            # pyright => (Interface) -> str

reveal_type(Interface.bar)  # mypy    => (Interface) -> str
                            # pyright => property

reveal_type(instance.foo)   # mypy + pyright => str
reveal_type(instance.bar)   # mypy + pyright => str

instance.foo = 42           # mypy    => error: Incompatible types in assignment
                            # pyright => error: "Literal[42]" is incompatible with "str" ('foo' is underlined)

instance.bar = 42           # mypy    => error: Incompatible types in assignment
                            # pyright => error: "Literal[42]" is incompatible with "str" ('42' is underlined)

instance.foo = 'lorem'      # mypy + pyright => fine
instance.bar = 'ipsum'      # mypy + pyright => fine
```

Comment: Wow, that required way more manual work than I had expected. Since you added the "(yet)" to your answer, do you know by any chance if there are plans to make properties generic? Seems like an obvious/useful addition

Comment: @amacati There are some issues about/related to this in *[python/typing](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/985)*, *[python/typeshed](https://github.com/python/typeshed/issues/4731)*, and *[python/mypy](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/8083)*. From the discussion at those issues, it seems that the main problem is backward compatibility.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't need much in terms of special property abilities, you can use type hinting with any variable, property, or attribute like so:

```py
class MyClass:
    '''Description of my class'''

    my_property: float = 5.6
```

In some editors, including VSCode, you may also add a doc string after a variable, attribute, or property as well.

(This is always valid Python, but not all editors will know to associate the doc string with the variable/property/attribute. Try it out to see if it works in your editor.)

```py
class MyClass:
    '''Description of my class'''

    my_property: float = 5.6
    '''Example description of `my_property`'''

    another_property: int = 4
    '''And another doc string here'''
```

Here's what it looks like in my version of VSCode:
[image]

Comment: I appreciate the solution, but as stated in my question, this declares the property as a variable of type string, not a property of type string. They behave differently in my use case, so I explicitly would like to mark them as properties, not variables.

Answer (score -1):

In your current implementation, the issue arises because the type hinting system doesn't recognize the properties created by your property_factory as properties with a specific type. One way to address this is to use the typing.cast function to explicitly cast the properties to the desired type. This way, you can provide more accurate type hints.

Here's how you can modify your code:

```
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import cast

class Interface:

    @staticmethod
    def property_factory(name: str) -> property:
        """Create a property depending on the name."""

        @property
        def _complex_property(self: Interface) -> str:
            # Do something complex with the provided name
            return name

        @_complex_property.setter
        def _complex_property(self: Interface, _: str):
            pass

        return cast(property, _complex_property)

    foo: str = property_factory("foo")
    bar: str = property_factory("bar")

def main():
    interface = Interface()
    value: str = interface.foo  # Now has the correct type hint

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

In this modification, I've added the cast(property, _complex_property) line to explicitly cast the created property to the property type. This allows you to specify the type hint for foo and bar as str.

While this addresses the type hinting issue, it's worth noting that using cast essentially tells the type checker to trust your assertion. So, make sure that the actual implementation adheres to the specified type to avoid potential runtime errors.

Comment: Your approach looks like the solution I was looking for. However, when I implement this in VSCode, foo and bar are still marked as variables of type string, not as properties. Is this a bug with VSCode? And do you know why `def foo(self) -> property[str]: ...` is not supported? It seems like the most logical solution to the problem.